Dominated Convergence Theorem and Norm convergence
Here is the theory I have in mind:

Dominated Convergence Theorem: $(X,A,\mu)$ measure space, $g$ a $[0,\infty]$-valued integrable function on $X$, $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$ $[-\infty,\infty]$-valued $A$-measurable functions on $X$ s.t. $f(x)=\lim_nf_n(x)$ and $|f_n(x)|\leq g(x)\ \forall\ n$ and for $\mu$-a.e. $x$. Then $f,f_1,f_2,\dots$ are integrable and $\int fd\mu=\lim_n\int f_nd\mu$.


Norm continuity: $\lim_n|f_n-f|_1=0$ implies $\lim_n|f_n|_1=|f|_1$ where $|f|_1=\int |f|d\mu$ for $f\in L^1(X,A,\mu)$.

I am reviewing normed spaces and thought of this question myself: Is there a relation between Dominated Convergence Theorem and norm convergence in $L^1$?

Your question is not clear. Are you asking if $f_n \to f$ a.e  and $|f_n-f|_1 \to 0$ implies $(f_n)$ is necessarily dominated by an integrable function? The answer to this is NO.

In short, no: the fact that a norm is continuous is in the topology it induces hold in general (and DCT doesn't play a role in the proof that the integral of the absolute value is a norm).

@geetha290krm Sorry, I am/was confused and gave a very incorrect argument. My question is simply if there is a connection between DCT and norm convergence as they seem very similar. And I agree with what you are saying, which would give an example of when DCT isn't applicable. For thoroughness, I'm thinking of the real line, Lebesgue measure and $f_n(x)=\chi_([n,n+1/n])$ with $f=0$. Is there a similar example where DCT is applicable and norm convergence isn't?

Sorry again for the language I'm using. What I meant was: Can we have $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. and dominated by an integrable function without $|f_n-f|\rightarrow 0$?

No, we can't. The hypothesis of DCT is strictly stronger than convergence in $L^1$.
